# Binding variable in generator expression

Tags: python, for-loop, scope, generator

Could you please help me?
I would like to write function which successively applies several functions to some iterable object and return list of results. I do not want to create temporary list object on each iteration step. Goal is to use lazy evaluation.

```
def applay(iterable, functions):
    res = iterable
    for f in functions:
        res = (f(i) for i in res)

    return list(res)

print applay([1,2,3], [lambda x: x+1, lambda y: y+2])
```

This does not work as f inside of each generator bind to the last function from function list. Can I avoid this python feature?

Look like I have found solution:

```
from itertools import repeat
from functools import partial

def applay(iterable, functions):

    res = arg_to_iter(iterable)
    for cur_f in functions:
        res = (f(r) for r, f in zip(res, partial(repeat, cur_f)()))

    return list(res)

print applay([1,2,3], [lambda x: x+1, lambda y: y+2])
```

Comment: This isn't a problem with the generator.. 

it's a problem with your lambda. Try just: ```funcs = [lambda x: x+i for i in range(3)]; print funcs[1](3); print funcs[2](3)```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I agree with you. My functions list was not created correctly. But I have updated it but original problem is still exist.

Comment: I  found this works:: def applay(it, funcs):
    r = [];
    for f in funcs:
        r += [f(i) for i in it];
    return r --- sorry about the format but answers have been disabled

Comment: Maybe it works. but I am looking for solution without temporary list objects